# Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I'm new in java and spring, I need to make a query to two tables with a 1 to N pacient->event relationship.

Repository:

```
public interface EventJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<Events2, Long> {

        @Query("select a.start,a.end, CONCAT(p.a_pat ,' ', p.a_mat ,' ',p.nombre) as title from events2,paciente p where e.rut_num=p.rut_num")
        List<Events2> getAllEvents();
        
    }
```

I got this error:

> Error creating bean with name 'eventJpaRepository':
>
> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.calendar.repository.EventJpaRepository.getAllEvents()!

Comment: Hello  will you add more details to the questions ? 1. is @query is native ? pacient to event relationship is 1 to N is egar  or lazy ? and if you just want to load all events why not to use the default method of jparepository  findall()

Comment: Hi, I dont have mapped any relationship on my entities, I just need to load all events but I need to get pacient name from pacient table, thats why I cannot use findall() method